# C# different values into one group

Tags: c#

if I have

```
var numbers = new List<string> { "1", "2", "2", "3", "3"};
```

and I wanna to get the values (below) from numbers (above)

```
[["1","2","3"],["2","3"]]
```

every array has the different value, so I will get 2 array

more example :
new List { "1", "2", "3", "3",}  to [["1","2","3"],["3"]]

rules:
different values in one array or list

Can anyone suggest how to do that easily? Thanks!

Comment: You state that you want to get the values from numbers? What does it mean? Could you please be more clear about what you want to do. I mean you should restate your question as I have this input and I would like to get this output. Furthermore, you have to show your effort and where you have got stuck. Thanks

Comment: from new List<string> { "1", "2", "2", "3", "3"} to [["1","2","3"],["2","3"]]

Comment: First of all, if they're numbers, store them as numbers. Secondly, you may need to clarify the algorithm. Do you want to partition the list into the largest possible sequences of consecutive numbers?

Comment: Because right now, I could answer: "Try `var result = new string[][] {{"1","2","3"},{"2","3"}};`" and it would answer your question.

Comment: @Ian - There might be a million ways to logically group those numbers that way. So one example isn't enough for us to be sure of what the rule is that you're looking for. Just for starters your source is in ascending order - does that matter? What if there were a "2" at the end? It's not clear.

Comment: `string[][] GetTheValues(List<string> l){ return new string[][] { new string[] {l[0],l[1],l[3]}, new string[] {l[2],l[4]} }; }`

Comment: No @poke, I think this is a better solution: `string[][] GetTheValues(List<string> l) { return new string[][] { new string[] { l[0], l[2], l[4] }, new string[] { l[1], l[3] } }; }`.

Comment: @Ian - Your question seems to be going downhill quickly. You need a better explanation than `new List { "1", "2", "3", "3",} to [["1","2","3"],["3"]]` before it gets closed. Please **explain** the rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
var numbers = new List<string> { "1", "2", "2", "3", "3"};

var lookup = numbers.ToLookup(n => n);

var results =
    Enumerable
        .Range(0, numbers.Count())
        .Select(n =>
            lookup
                .SelectMany(l => l.Skip(n).Take(1))
                .ToList())
        .Where(xs => xs.Any())
        .ToList();
```

I get this:

[image: result]